# Runtime error while using vectors in c++ with large number of inputs

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error, malloc, memory-corruption

I was trying to solve a hackerearth problems to understand c++ better.
The Task is as follows :
The first line will consists of one integer T denoting the number of test cases.
For each test case:

1. The first line consists of two integers N and K, N being the number of elements in the array and K denotes the number of steps of rotation.
2. The next line consists of N space separated integers , denoting the elements of the array A.

So,If the input is like

```
1
5 2
1 2 3 4 5
```

The output should be

```
4 5 1 2 3
```

The code that i have written is as follows :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;


void ans(int r,vector<int> &a)
{
    reverse(a.begin(),a.end());
    reverse(a.begin(),a.begin()+r);
    reverse(a.begin()+r,a.end());
}


int main() {
    int testno;
    cin>>testno;
    int size,rotation,temp;
    vector<vector<int>> arr(testno);
    for(int i=0;i<testno;i++)
    {
        cin>>size;
        cin>>rotation;
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            cin>>temp;
            arr[i].push_back(temp);
        };
        ans(rotation,arr[i]);
    };
    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr[i].size();j++)
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        cout<<"\n";
    };
}
```

This code works fine for small test-cases or numbers.
But when the input is huge,I get the following error :

```
Execution failed.

Stack Trace:
*** Error in `/hackerearth/CPP17_a870_37de_35ba_2748/s_3a8f_d922_ff44_e648.cpp.out': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x0000000001b0ad50 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777f5)[0x7f10c1df57f5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x82679)[0x7f10c1e00679]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x54)[0x7f10c1e021d4]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_Znwm+0x15)[0x7f10c2405c75]
/hackerearth/CPP17_a870_37de_35ba_2748/s_3a8f_d922_ff44_e648.cpp.out[0x400f62]
/hackerearth/CPP17_a870_37de_35ba_2748/s_3a8f_d922_ff44_e648.cpp.out[0x400bbb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f10c1d9e840]
/hackerearth/CPP17_a870_37de_35ba_2748/s_3a8f_d922_ff44_e648.cpp.out[0x400d49]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 28 /hackerearth/CPP17_a870_37de_35ba_2748/s_3a8f_d922_ff44_e648.cpp.out
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 07:00 28 /hackerearth/CPP17_a870_37de_35ba_2748/s_3a8f_d922_ff44_e648.cpp.out
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 07:00 28 /hackerearth/CPP17_a870_37de_35ba_2748/s_3a8f_d922_ff44_e648.cpp.out
01af8000-01b2a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [heap]
7f10bc000000-7f10bc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f10bc021000-7f10c0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f10c1a75000-7f10c1b7d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 48154 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f10c1b7d000-7f10c1d7c000 ---p 00108000 ca:01 48154 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f10c1d7c000-7f10c1d7d000 r--p 00107000 ca:01 48154 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f10c1d7d000-7f10c1d7e000 rw-p 00108000 ca:01 48154 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f10c1d7e000-7f10c1f3e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 48130 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f10c1f3e000-7f10c213e000 ---p 001c0000 ca:01 48130 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f10c213e000-7f10c2142000 r--p 001c0000 ca:01 48130 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f10c2142000-7f10c2144000 rw-p 001c4000 ca:01 48130 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f10c2144000-7f10c2148000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f10c2148000-7f10c215f000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 18214 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f10c215f000-7f10c235e000 ---p 00017000 ca:01 18214 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f10c235e000-7f10c235f000 r--p 00016000 ca:01 18214 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f10c235f000-7f10c2360000 rw-p 00017000 ca:01 18214 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f10c2360000-7f10c2533000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 16581 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
7f10c2533000-7f10c2732000 ---p 001d3000 ca:01 16581 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
7f10c2732000-7f10c273d000 r--p 001d2000 ca:01 16581 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
7f10c273d000-7f10c2740000 rw-p 001dd000 ca:01 16581 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
7f10c2740000-7f10c2743000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f10c2743000-7f10c2769000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 48198 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f10c2948000-7f10c294e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f10c2967000-7f10c2968000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f10c2968000-7f10c2969000 r--p 00025000 ca:01 48198 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f10c2969000-7f10c296a000 rw-p 00026000 ca:01 48198 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f10c296a000-7f10c296b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff76e54000-7fff76e75000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [stack]
7fff76f09000-7fff76f0b000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 [vvar]
7fff76f0b000-7fff76f0d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 [vsyscall]
```

I don't understand why there is a runtime malloc error? What exactly is happening that is leading to this error for large inputs? Why is there memory corruption? Am I trying to access memory not allocated to me during the runtime? If so,Where? 
The link to the problem,if needed is :  https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/codemonk/

Comment: Memory corruption means memory corruption. You program edits some memory that doesn't belong to it. `valgrind` is a tool that will probably spot it very quickly.

Comment: So,I can't use the stack-trace or Backtrace to debug whats going on? Is there no 'method' or way to make sense of these things?

Comment: Are you sure at no time that r is outside range of the vector? Also, is there some reason you need to store all the data? You could do this with a single vector and a single loop: get the values, do the rotation thing, print the results, loop. Any chance the input is so large that you run into a process limit allocating it all?

Comment: Do you really have to store the result of all the tests? Just keep _one_ test alive, print the answer and get on with the next.

Comment: @Vivek the stack trace will just tell you when malloc noticed its memory had been corrupted, not when the memory got corrupted to begin with

Comment: Debugged it using the old method of commenting suspicious section and running again. Found the culprit. Turns out some test cases had `rotation` higher than the size of vector.So just updated `rotation` to` rotation%size`. Working fine now.

Comment: Did you also try the `std::rotate` function?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I didn't know STL had a built-in function! I looked into it.Turns out it would have produced the same error since r was out of bounds of the vector. But ,Thanks a lot for educating me:) I will start using it from now on.

Comment: @Vivek You're welcome. `std::rotate` is likely doing the rotation in a pretty efficient way. It's a nice little helper function. Since you figured out the problem already, I won't write an answer (you can do that yourself if you want to) but I made an example of how you could approach the problem without storing all the data from previous tests [here](https://godbolt.org/z/seG7jra5K).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah,Checked it out! I could do that also to save memory:)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out some test cases had `rotation` higher than the size of vector.So just updated rotation to `rotation%size`. Working fine now.